# Problems with using VML in mail templates when forwarding the mail

Tags: html-email, email-templates

I am total newbie so it'd be awesome if you could answer this in a simple explanation :)

I am programming a mail where I need live text on top of an image, therefore I have used bulletproof backgrounds with VML to make it work in Outlook.

Everything looks good, unless I forward the mail in non-Outlook clients, e.g. Yahoo. Then the one block I used VML in just disappears and there's a blank white box. This is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="header2" background="some_image.jpg" bgcolor="#63a924" width="670" height="149px" valign="top" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:670px; height:149px;">
            <v:fill type="frame" src="some_image.jpg" color="#63a924" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->
                <div>   
                    <table class="table_header" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="670px" style="height: 149px; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace:0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="headline" valign="middle" width="600px" style="height: 149px; color: white; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 4px; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; font-size: 32px;">
                                 Some Text
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
              </div>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
            </td> 
        </tr>
```

Since it works in Outlook when forwarding, this is probably a client-specific problem? Do you know a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Chances are the url of the background image gets changed. Have a look at it and see if any new classes get added or overwritten that might be causing it. In general there is nothing we can do with forwarded emails. Each email client adds its own code to it.

Comment: @Syfer Thanks for your answer. I now found a solution by also putting a background image for the table with the text. Unfortunately I found a new bug when forwarding the mail in Outlook. The user receiving the forwarded mail can still read the text but the background image is broken. How you describe it I guess I can do nothing about that because we can not surpres Outlook changing the code?